# How to highlight Python syntax in LaTeX using verbments and utf8

Tags: python, unicode

I'm using Latex and the `verbments` package to display some python 3 code (with syntax highlighting) inside a document, but I have a problem with UTF-8. I'm using the `verbments` package

```
\begin{pyglist}[language=python, encoding=utf8]
print(``Mañana será otro día'')
\end{pyglist}
```

I use `pdflatex -shell-escape  DocMaestro.tex` to produce a pdf file, but nothing happens.

I see in the console log this error:

`Error while highlighting:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 10: invalid continuation byte
   (file "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pygments/lexer.py", line 164, in get_tokens)
 (./DocMaestro.pyg.sty) (./DocMaestro.pyg.vrb)) [62]`

I've also noticed that when i run latex another file called `DocMaestro.pyg.lst` is created this file contains the following information:

``` print(``Mañana será otro día'') ```

but is encoded in ISO-8859-15 instead of UTF-8 as all my other files.